# MongoDB: FieldPath field names may not contain ‘.’

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a `$lookup` `from` a collection whose documents look this way:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid":"5f1957c7cdf25116937ed3ef"},
    "idSensor": {"$numberLong":"3"},
    ...
    "data":
    {
        "inicio":"2019-11-28T16:09:08+01:00",
        "fin":"2019-11-28T16:09:18+01:00",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I deliver them to the `$unwind` stage just `as` `"array"`, and then I try a `$match`:

```
[
...
    {
        "$match":
        {
            "$expr":
            {
                "$and": 
                [
                    {"array.idSensor": 3},
                    {"$gt": ["array.data.inicio", "ISODate('2021-02-28T23:59:59+01:00')"]},
                    {"$lt": ["array.data.fin", "ISODate('2021-03-15T00:00:01+01:00')"]}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
...
]
```

Here's where I'm getting an error message:

> "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'."

Filtering just by `"array.idSensor"` is OK, I checked it, so the problem lies within the dates.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: no need of $expr expression match see the working you can match your conditions directly [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Drq9jOM5PSQ), make sure you have ISO date in your collection.

Comment: I also deleted `ISODate()` and now it seems it works, thanks a lot!